# AABB intersect BoundingSphere only working on one side

Tags: c++, 3d, collision, aabb

So I am trying to make it so a sphere will correctly collide with a AABB. But for some reason it will only happen on one side of the AABB. All the other sides act as if they have no collision.

```
    float  dmin;
    float  r2 = pow(m_Radius, 2);
    dmin = 0;

    if (m_Center.GetX() < other.GetMinExtents().GetX())
        dmin += pow(m_Center.GetX() - other.GetMinExtents().GetX(), 2);
    else if (m_Center.GetX() > other.GetMaxExtents().GetX())
        dmin += pow(m_Center.GetX() - other.GetMaxExtents().GetX(), 2);

    if (m_Center.GetY() < other.GetMinExtents().GetY())
        dmin += pow(m_Center.GetY() - other.GetMinExtents().GetY(), 2);
    else if (m_Center.GetY() > other.GetMaxExtents().GetY())
        dmin += pow(m_Center.GetY() - other.GetMaxExtents().GetY(), 2);

    if (m_Center.GetZ() < other.GetMinExtents().GetZ())
        dmin += pow(m_Center.GetZ() - other.GetMinExtents().GetZ(), 2);
    else if (m_Center.GetZ() > other.GetMaxExtents().GetZ())
        dmin += pow(m_Center.GetZ() - other.GetMaxExtents().GetZ(), 2);

    if (dmin < r2)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a hunch... you didn't specify which exactly platform and compiler you are testing this on, but if the pow() function is implemented naively, it may fail for negative values of the first argument.
[According to the specs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/), it should work correctly for negative values of base, as long as the exponent is an integer. But a naively implemented general-purpose pow(base, exponent) could be doing something like exp(e, ln(base)*exponent)), and that would return NaN for negative values of base.

Which would have exactly the effects that you describe - it would work only on the side where all three axes generate positive deltas in your example code.

In any case, it is always safer to do the squaring manually, or implement an inline like:
`float square(float a) { return a*a; }`
for cleaner code.